# How can I capture audio input from 2 mics of my android phone real time and simultaneously

Tags: android, eclipse, signal-processing, audio-recording, microphone

I have a requirement where I need audio from both the mics on my android phone **simultaneously** in order to do some signal processing using Eclipse. Do you think it is possible to do this? Also can you suggest a method to start recording for both mics **realtime** simultaneously?

For two instances of class AudioRecord, if I pass audio source as MIC and CAMCORDER respectively, will I be able to capture two separate mic inputs simultaneously? I am not sure if the mics will work in parallel, and also do not know how to get them to start recording at the same time.

Any input regarding this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you specify `CHANNEL_IN_STEREO` and use the `MIC` `AudioSource` you should get the audio from one mic in the left channel, and from the other mic in the right channel (assuming that the device has at least 2 microphones).

Comment: Thanks @Michael.. But then can you please guide me as to how I can separate stereo input into each of the channel audio data? I understand that we are going to receive audio in bytes..