# How to access multiple build-in microphones on iPhone 4s (5, 5s)?

Tags: iphone, audio, microphone, stereo-3d

Recently, I'm working on  a project using the build-in microphones recording the stereo sound. And then doing some signal processing. However, it seems like there is no specific solution to this question.

There is a link showing that it is quite reasonable only using the build-in microphones doing the stereo recording.

https://audioboo.fm/boos/1102187-recording-in-stereo-from-the-iphone-5#t=0m20s

However, I still do not know how to do it! Is there someone solving this problem?

There are some resources showing how to access different build-in mic.
[use rear microphone of iphone 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198953/use-rear-microphone-of-iphone-5)

Also, it may quite easy using an Android phone implementing this project.
 [How to access the second mic android such as Galaxy 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418267/how-to-access-the-second-mic-android-such-as-galaxy-3) ,
[How can I capture audio input from 2 mics of my android phone real time and simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400642/how-can-i-capture-audio-input-from-2-mics-of-my-android-phone-real-time-and-simu)

Comment: Have you found a solution meanwhile?

Comment: not yet. Seems that there's no relative API. I used Samsung Note 3 instead and got the solution.

Comment: The solution I got used in Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594750/split-two-channels-of-audiorecord-of-channel-in-stereo