# Android - AudioRecord splitting of 2 channels in channel_in_stereo

Tags: java, android, audio, record, android-audiorecord

I came across this link but I am not sure how to implement it 
[split two channels of AudioRecord of CHANNEL_IN_STEREO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594750/split-two-channels-of-audiorecord-of-channel-in-stereo)

I want to separate the data received in the left and right channel

Below is my code

```
for(int i = 0; i < read/2; i = i + 2)
{
    leftChannelAudioData[i] = data[2*i];
    leftChannelAudioData[i+1] = data[2*i+1];
    rightChannelAudioData[i] =  data[2*i+2];
    rightChannelAudioData[i+1] = data[2*i+3];
}
```

Full source can be found here: http://pastebin.com/ntm1mHG0

I have tried from line 298 to line 322 but it does not work. It crashes my application instead :/

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your close but if you consider the case where `i==read/2-1` you can see the `data[2*i+2]` reads beyond the end of the array. Since you are going through for samples per iteration, you need to change the for loop like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < read/4; i = i + 4)
{
    leftChannelAudioData[i] = data[4*i];
    leftChannelAudioData[i+1] = data[4*i+1];
    rightChannelAudioData[i] =  data[4*i+2];
    rightChannelAudioData[i+1] = data[4*i+3];
}
```

But the issue now is that you are reading 2 samples for the left followed by 2 samples for the right (e.g. LLRRLLRR) but audio is normally interleaved LRLRLR.

```
for(int i = 0; i < read/2; i = i + 2)
{
    leftChannelAudioData[i] = data[2*i];
    rightChannelAudioData[i+1] = data[2*i+1];
}
```

A more robust way to work it that would work for any number of channels is something like this:

```
double[][] deinterleaveData(double[] samples, int numChannels)
{
   // assert(samples.length() % numChannels == 0);
   int numFrames  = samples.length() / numChannels;

   double[][] result = new double[numChannels][];
   for (int ch = 0 ; ch < numChannels ; ch++)
   {
       result[ch] = new double[numFrames];
       for (int i = 0 ; i < numFrames ; i++)
       {
           result[ch][i] = samples[numChannels*i+ch];
       }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks! :) Would you mind explaining how does the deinterleaveData method works? How does it split the 2 channels into 1?

Comment: It splits a single array where the channels are interleaved (1,2,1,2,1,2,...) into an array for each channel (1,1,1,...),(2,2,2,...)

Comment: thanks! but may I know what's the reason/purpose behind splitting the channel if I want to do a filtering (eg: bandpass filter)

Comment: Filters need to operate on each channel independently and the implementations of the filters typically expect the data that way. So you would have 2 instances of your filter and feed a channel to each. Less often the filter will support multichannel and will hide those details from you in which case they might take interleaved data.

Comment: thanks so much! if I may, I would like to ask 2 more questions.

I would like to understand how writeAudioDataToFile (Line 103) works and copyWaveFile (Line 159) works. (Based on this link: https://github.com/krvarma/AudioRecorder/blob/master/src/com/varma/samples/audiorecorder/RecorderActivity.java) 

Thank You so much.