# Android - AudioRecord: How to separate left and right channels in stereo recording mode

Tags: android, audiorecord, lame

I am using AudioRecord class of android sdk to record raw audio and then I am encoding it with lame mp3 encoder. For this I have to separate the left and right chaanels in stereo recording mode like this.

```
bytesEncoded = Lame.encode(left, isMono ? left : right, samplesRead, mp3Buf, mp3Buf.length);
```

How to separate the left and right channels from a buffer into its own buffer?

I have tried using this but it gives sound with gaps. 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725339/android-audiorecord-splitting-of-2-channels-in-channel-in-stereo)

The following method is working but it is adding noise in background:`

```
private int readStereo(short[] left, short[] right, int numSamples) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[numSamples * 4];
        int index = 0;

        if (audioRecorder == null)
            return -1;

        int bytesRead = audioRecorder.read(buf, 0, numSamples * 4);

        for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i+=2) {
            short val = byteToShortLE(buf[0], buf[i+1]);
            if (i % 4 == 0) {
                left[index] = val;
            } else {
                right[index] = val;
                index++;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }`


private static short byteToShortLE(byte b1, byte b2) {
        return (short) (b1 & 0xFF | ((b2 & 0xFF) << 8));
    }
```