# Converting a Wav file into a byte array Java Android

Tags: android, arrays, audio, byte, wav

I am looking for a method to convert a Wav file into a byte array in Android(Java). I know how to do in Eclipse using javax.sound.sampled, but it doesn't exist in Android and I can find how to import it. Does someone know an equivalent for Android?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please look at the link if this helps. [Audio file get left/right channels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132063/audio-file-get-left-right-channels/40114009#40114009)

Comment: You want to just read the file into a byte array? Or do you want to have the sound sample values?

Comment: The sound sample values, but I think I know how to pass from bytes to to double array

Comment: Create a blank bytearray. Read the WAVE file and copy its bytes from 45th onwards (if 44 byte header but sometimes can be 46) into the new bytearray. Now you have the PCM (after skipping/removing WAVE header)